# Is there a way to automate the loading of data to Power BI?

Tags: python, automation, powerbi, report, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power BI template set up and I need to create weekly reports using this template. I only use a single CSV file per report and the structures of the files are all identical (same number of columns, same headers, etc).

NOTE: A **new** CSV file is downloaded and used every time I make a report. In other words, every week I download a new CSV file and make a new report from that file.

Right now, my Power BI template has a parameter that asks the user to input the file path to the CSV file before loading the report. I want to know if there is a way I can automate the following:

1. Opening the Power BI template file
2. Inputting the file path into the parameter field
3. Pressing the "Load" button

I understand that I could use Python and PyAutoGUI to control my desktop and, by extension, Power BI. Just wanted to know if there's another way to automate?

Comment: You can load you file as dataset, then refresh the data based on schedule, so the user only need to update the csv data and the rest is auto one.

Comment: Hi @KinSiang, if I use a new CSV file every time I make a report, could refreshing it still work?

Comment: CSV file should work also, as long as you store your file in microsoft sharepoint and connect it, then schedule the refresh dataset as your wish.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your task. Here is number of step you need to take.

1. Download and install the PowerBi personal gateway on you machine.
   https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/
2. Go to settings of your dataset in PowerBi service (in your browser)
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE9Bc.png
3. The gateway installed on your machine should be detected like in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3MS1.png
4. Setup a refresh schedule in this part of the dataset settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/LByMO.png
5. Once all of this is done, you do not need to manually do upload/publishing from your machine. Gateway will upload your new and fresh data to the report on its own.

Cheers!!